# How to set up Debezium SMT with Graal

Tags: debezium, graalvm

I am following the latest stable (Version 2.4) at https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/filtering.html to try set up SMT using Graal. I am stuck on step 3

[image]

I cannot find `graalvm.js`, or `graalvm.js.scriptengine`, even after extracting and going through both the releases at https://github.com/oracle/graaljs and https://www.graalvm.org

[image]

Comment: you can add those to the [pom xml and use them](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/js/ScriptEngine/#prerequisite) directly from a java project. So the release you downloaded probably has files only for linux. in the lib folder you probably see jsvm.so which is the shared library for linux, therefore when you run SMT it will use that so file in linux. in Graalvm world everything turns to native binary SO is the native library for linux.